# IEとEdge IEモードの判定

Tags: javascript, html

表題の通りですが、IEとEdge(Chromium版)のIEモードとを判別する方法はありますか？

userAgentは同じ内容でした。

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; Trident/7.0; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; Tablet PC 2.0; Zoom 3.6.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko
```

IEとEdgeのIEモードで動作が異なる所があるので、何か判別出来る項目等があればいいのですが…

よろしくお願いします。

追記.2021/11/02
document.documentModeとdocument.uniqueIDが取得できるかどうかで判別しようとしたのですが
こちらも、IE、EdgeのIEモード共に値が取得できました。
※IE以外だと上記プロパティは取得できないとのことでしたがEdgeのIEモードでも取得できます

Comment: この記事あたりが参考になるかも。[Check if user is using IE](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19999388/9014308)

Comment: 参考URLありがとうございます。
userAgent以外にdocument.documentModeとdocument.uniqueIDで判別できるということは知らなかったのですが、EdgeのIEモードでも上記プロパティは取得できまして、この項目でも判別できないようでした。

Comment: 上記記事のこちらの[回答](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21712356/9014308)でIEかEdgeかを切り分けられそうですが。その上でdocument.documentModeとかdocument.uniqueIDが存在するかしないかでIEモードか否かを識別できるのでは？ あるいはこんな記事もあるようです。[IEのために｜IE判定とバベルとポリフィル](https://qiita.com/tomokei5634/items/5e57d30466f1ee1f0ce9)

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。
そこで切り分けられると思っていたのですが、1つ前の私のコメントは
EdgeのIEモードでもdocument.documentModeとdocument.uniqueIDがIEと同様に値が取得できてしまいますということです。
古いバージョンのEdgeでは値が入ってこなかったのでしょうか？
最新のEdgeのIEモードでしか試してないので、当時は値が入ってなかったかどうかまでは調べられておりませんが、、

Comment: そういう単一の判定ではなくて、ブラウザがIEかEdgeかで切り分けて、その後EdgeならChromium版か否か、そしてdocument.documentModeとdocument.uniqueIDが取得できるか否かの3つを組み合わせれば判定できるのでは？ ということです。

Comment: 勘違いしてしまいました。申し訳ありません。
たしかにdocument.uniqueIDはIEとEdgeIEモードで別の値が返ってきたのですが
それがどの環境(PCやバージョン)でも固有のものなのかの確認まではしておりませんので
その辺りを確認して判別に使用できるか調査してみます。
ありがとうございました。